# Two links appears for one user weirdly - Laravel models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have a many-to-many relationship between my User and Wallet models.

**Wallet Model**

```
public function users() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_wallet', 'user_id', 'wallet_id');
}
```

**User Model**

```
public function wallets() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Wallet::class, 'user_wallet', 'user_id', 'wallet_id')->withPivot('balance');;
}
```

Then in my Blade file, I tried the following.

```
@forelse($user->wallets as $wallet)
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ $wallet->name }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ $wallet->pivot->balance }}
        </td>
    <td>
        <a href="{{ route('user.WalletTransaction', ['walletId'=>$wallet->id,'userId'=>$user->id]) }}" class="fa fa-exchange text-dark mt-1" />
    </td>
</tr>
@empty
    <td colspan="5" class="text-center">No wallet exist</td>
@endforelse
```

It works fine, but the problem is, it shows two links in the table for one user. However, it should be showing one.

[image]

And if I do:

```
@forelse($user->wallets as $wallet)
   {{ count(array($user)) }}
@empty
    <td colspan="5" class="text-center">
        No wallet exist
    </td>
@endforelse
```

The result would be **1**.

The problem is coming from `'userId' => $user->id` of the link. Because if I remove it, only **1** link would appear, which is correct. But still, I do need the `userId` and don't know how to pass that into the route name.

So what's going wrong here? I need one link for each user, and I don't know why it prints two of them.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase The problem is coming from `'userId'=>$user->id` of the link. Because if I remove it and only pass one parameter, only 1 link would be appeared which is correct. But I don't know what to pass as **userId** instead.

Comment: I'm not sure it's correct that you have both `belongsToMany` relationships defined with with the same keys in the same order ie `'user_wallet','user_id','wallet_id'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@forelse($user->wallets as $wallet)
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ $wallet->name }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ $wallet->pivot->balance }}
        </td>
    <td>
        <a href="{{ route('user.WalletTransaction', ['walletId'=>$wallet->id,'userId'=>$user->id]) }}" class="fa fa-exchange text-dark mt-1" />
    </td>
</tr>
@empty
    <td colspan="5" class="text-center">No wallet exist</td>
@endforelse`
```

Doesn't `$user->wallets` returns collection of all wallets associated with each user?

maybe you need to check if any user has more than one wallet or if you want to show only one you can user `$user->wallets[0]` to show the first wallet model since its a collection